# What happen after BackgroundService end his assigned task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) i implemented a library that allow to my web apis to create and run tasks in background. Basically, what i do is to create a `QueuedHostedService` (which inherit from `BackgroundService`) which contain a task to complete and add it to a queue. Then this queue get progressively emptied by running this tasks concurrently (on different threads i suppose). The following is the abstract class of the `BackgroundService`

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    protected BackgroundService();

    public virtual void Dispose();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Triggered when the application host is ready to start the service.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   cancellationToken:
    //     Indicates that the start process has been aborted.
    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   cancellationToken:
    //     Indicates that the shutdown process should no longer be graceful.
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<StopAsync>d__4))]
    public virtual Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     This method is called when the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService starts.
    //     The implementation should return a task that represents the lifetime of the long
    //     running operation(s) being performed.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   stoppingToken:
    //     Triggered when Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService.StopAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    //     is called.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A System.Threading.Tasks.Task that represents the long running operations.
    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
```

The thing i don't know is, what happen exactly after the `Task` is completed? Do i need to do something (like using the Dispose method) or does the system take care of releasing the resource allocated to the background thread?

**EDIT** i'm adding the implementation of the class `QueuedHostedService` which implement the `ExecuteAsinc()` methods

```
public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private static ILog logger = LogExtensions.GetClassLogger();

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.MethodEnter();

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Error occurred executing {nameof(workItem)}. with the following exception {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        logger.MethodLeave();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to return a `Task` from these methods that lets the system know effectively when you're done?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto this isn't a TPL question, it's about the background tasks [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2). This is a well-known ASP.NET Core technique

Comment: @DanieleSartori you added the correct tags. You should have added the `asp.net-core-hosted-services` tag too

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's an [ASP.NET Core class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2), not the OP's

Comment: Yes, but they have to supply, at the least, their own implementation of `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs) might be helpful.

Comment: @DanieleSartori what does *your* code look like? `ExecuteAsync` is a "worker" method that is expected to keep running until `StopAsync` is called, or it decides to end itself. If `StopAsync` is called, the cancellation token is signaled. That's what [the documentation example shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks). The worker tries to pull items from the queue until cancellation is signalled

Comment: Whether you need to clean up anything depends on your actual implementation, eg whether your service class contains any items that need disposing. The queued Task processor shown in the docs is a simple example only that doesn't need anything more. An *email* processor would probably queue email messages and use eg MailKit to send the messages. In this case stopping would probably include disposing any client objects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i was wondering if i should call the StopAsync. I implemented exactly what is written inside the example. So i have to signal the cancellation manually?

Comment: @DanieleSartori no you don't. Kirk Larkin pointed to the [actual source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs). Calling `StopAsync()` will signal the cancellation token

Comment: @DanieleSartori a final note - in the code, `BackgroundService.Dispose()` also signals cancellation. This means, that when the DI container terminates and calls `Dispose()` on all `IDisposable` instances, it will also call it on the services, telling them to stop

Comment: The task that i'm running is pretty straighforward, basically import a list of files inside the db. There is no return, and i expect that when the task is completed, anything that was "hosting" the task is shutted down. That's why i wanted to know if i need to perform anything further.

Comment: @DanieleSartori the background service hosts the infrastructure for handling *all* import jobs, not only a single one. The controller that receives the files should post the import job to the queue. This would allow you to accept multiple jobs too, but only execute one at a time. The queued service would process one of them at a time.

Comment: @DanieleSartori **on the other hand** the job function itself should take care of logging, error handling, disposing, reacting to cancellation requests etc. If it throws, the entire service goes down. If it gets a cancellation request it may mean that the site is going down soon and it can't finish importing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your advice. I surely need to deepen my knowledge about this topic.